# Rails number_to_phone: Remove country code from phone number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application that stores phone numbers as `'+11231231234'`. To make it easier for the user, I convert it to: `+1(123) 123-1234` in the view. I use the `number_to_phone` helper in rails to do it:

```
<%= number_to_phone(call.From, :area_code => true) %>
```

I also want to remove the `+1` from the view. What would I need to write to remove the first two characters of the phone number if the first two characters are `+1`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
number_to_phone(call.From, :area_code => true).gsub(/^\+\d/, '')
```

Comment: You are the man Kyle! I'll accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me

Comment: Does this handle a country code like +94, just looking in to the regex, it handles only one digit country codes, but there can be up to 3.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
number_to_phone(call.From, :area_code => true)[2..-1]
```

Of course this is valid only if you always want to remove the first two characters but it's easier on the cpu :)